# what does this error messsage "Invalid token character ':' in token "Accept:text"" mean in spring mvc 3?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Stacktrace is listed below. Really could not figure out what it means. Thanks for any help.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token character ':' in token "Accept:text"
        at org.springframework.http.MediaType.checkToken(MediaType.java:282) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.MediaType.<init>(MediaType.java:254) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:584) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaTypes(MediaType.java:602) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.getMediaTypes(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:306) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.resolveViewName(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:366) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1078) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Comment: how do you get it? can you just give us more scenario/code/information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception mean that you have incorrect mediaType format. the correct media type is "application/json", "text/html", "image/png";

I just looked at the the source code of `org.springframework.http.MediaType` and these are correct separators for MediaType.

```
   BitSet separators = new BitSet(128);
    separators.set('(');
    separators.set(')');
    separators.set('<');
    separators.set('>');
    separators.set('@');
    separators.set(',');
    separators.set(';');
    separators.set(':');
    separators.set('\\');
    separators.set('\"');
    separators.set('/');
    separators.set('[');
    separators.set(']');
    separators.set('?');
    separators.set('=');
    separators.set('{');
    separators.set('}');
    separators.set(' ');
    separators.set('\t');
```

`':'` is not defined there and this is the reason why does this exception is thrown, now this is your turn to find out why do you have Accept HTTP Header parameter instead of correct media Type ("application/json", "image/jpg", "application/octec-stream", etc...).

Hope it helps.

Comment: ':' is defined there in fact. i5 is right below ';'. But you answer helps a lot. thanks.

Comment: well I missed it :) but what the problem was?

Comment: ok. Figured it out. Tured out the Accept header we received is "Accept:Accept:text/html"!

Comment: nice :) now I understand what happened.